# OpenLayers - Add according popup text to marker array

Tags: popup, openlayers, markers

I have a probably rather basic problem in OpenLayers, it would be really great if someone could help me out on this one.

I have an array of markers, which should each have a different popup box text. However, I fail in applying the according text to a marker. I tried to do this via another array for the content of the popup boxes. However, i couldn't relate the correct text to a marker.  Here is my code:

```
var vs_locations = [
[13.045240, 47.8013271],
[13.145240, 47.8013271],
[13.245240, 47.8013271],
];

var popupContentHTML = [
"Text for marker with loc[0]",
"Text for marker with loc[1]",
"Text for marker with loc[2]"
];

function addVS(){

  for (var i = 0; i < vs_locations.length;i++){
    var loc = vs_locations[i];
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(volksschulen, new OpenLayers.LonLat(loc[0],loc[1],loc[2]).transform(proj4326,proj900913));
    feature.closeBox = true;
    feature.data.icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('coffeehouse.png');
    feature.popupClass =  OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
     'autoSize': true, 
    });
    marker = feature.createMarker();
    volksschulen.addMarker(marker);
    feature.data.popupContentHTML = ; //Here should be the text according to the marker
    feature.data.overflow = "auto";
    marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
    feature.popup = feature.createPopup(feature.closeBox);
    map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    feature.popup.hide();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
feature.data.popupContentHTML = popupContentHTML[i];
```

assuming the length of your location array matches your text array, both in length anf position